# Add captcha code after the comment field in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, comments

I sent the comment field to the end of the comments form using the code below :

```
function customize_comment_form_fields( $fields ) {
    $comment_field = $fields['comment'];
    unset( $fields['comment'] );
    $fields['comment'] = $comment_field;
    return $fields;
} add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'customize_comment_form_fields' );
```

Now I want to put the captcha code after the comment field, I checked the comment-template.php file, but I didn't find any action that I want to hook to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
function add_captcha_to_comment_form() {
    // Add your captcha code here
}
add_action( 'comment_form_after_fields', 'add_captcha_to_comment_form' );
```